# Typescript definition file - HelloWorld

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript-typings

`Newbie Question`

I have a TypeScript file that uses an extension to jQuery:

```
function Something() {
     $.stuff.removeAll(); 
}
```

I am trying to write a definition file for `stuff`, but am stuck. I tried this:

```
declare namespace JQueryStuff {
  interface Stuff{
    removeAll(): void;
  }
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    stuff(): JQueryStuff.Stuff;
}
```

TypeScript intellisence in Visual Studio picks up `"Stuff"` but not `removeAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it possible without digging too much is aliasing the `stuff` object with the `JQueryStatic` merged interface declaration.

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    stuff: JQueryStuff.Stuff;
}
```

Let me know if this covers your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how - Complete answer

```
interface Stuff{
removeAll(): void;
add(options: {
    title: string;
    text: string;
    class_name: string;
    sticky: boolean;
   });
}


interface JQueryStatic {

   stuff: Stuff;

}
```